# Google Cloud Platform Natural Language API v1beta2

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-natural-language

I am doing my dissertation on sentiment analysis on transcriptions of oral testimonies and have a few questions/clarifications regarding the programming behind Google Cloud's Natural Language API v1beta2.

1. I assume that it is a combination of lexicon-based methods and machine learning based methods of sentiment analysis but would appreciate confirmation of this.
2. What language model does Google NLP use? (I am guessing something involving deep learning and Tensorflow but am not sure)
3. What source material was the language model trained on? And was 
         anything like SentiWordNet or WordNet used?
4. If the API can detect both implicit and explicit sentiment?
5. Is the tool only capable of working in English or can it translate/trace sentiment in, for example, German or Polish?

I am open to any and all answers. Also, if anyone knows of any official Google document which lists this information that would also be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

We're currently using a large CNN implemented in TF. The model in the Cloud NL API does not use a LM. The API can detect both implicit and explicit sentiment, but it does not differentiate between them. The Sentiment API supports English, Spanish, French, German, Portuguese, Korean, Japanese, and Chinese

Source: I'm the Product Manager for NLU Research @ Google/Alphabet.